# p:galleria is not faded at the bottom, as is the case on the PrimeFaces showcase page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 7.0 on WildFly 16, JSF 2.3. (I also tried with PrimeFaces 6.2- but nothing changed).

I am using `p:galleria` tag as follows:

```
    <p:galleria value="#{exposeBean.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="false">
    <p:graphicImage id="image" value="#{image}" alt="#{image}" title="#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>
```

The above functionality works as expected, however the picture currenlty chosen does not fade at the bottom, where the rest of the images of the gallery are shown- see here:
[image]

What can be the reason, how can I solve it?

My minimal, working example seems to have something to do with the size of the images I use (at least, it seems to be like this.) :

https://github.com/alexmivonwien/pf.gall.git

After comparing the generated HTML and CSS in my case and in the case of the primeface galleria showcase I found the following difference:

1.) My own generated HTML and CSS:

[image]

note that the first "li" child under the "ul" element

```
<ul class="ui-galleria-panel-wrapper" style="width: 500px; height: 313px;">
```

has the CSS style (there is no display:none here):

```
<li class="ui-galleria-panel" style="width: 500px; height: 313px;">
```

2.) The HTML and CSS on the primefaces showcase:

[image]

Note that the first "li" element under the "ul" element

```
<ul class="ui-galleria-panel-wrapper" style="width: 500px; height: 313px;">
```

has the css style (there is a display:none here):

```
<li class="ui-galleria-panel" style="width: 500px; height: 313px; display: none;">
```

Comment: Look for differences in applied css

Comment: This looks like its on purpose as in the filmstrip the active one gets the style "ui-galleria-frame-active".

Comment: @Kukeltje I found one difference (see my edited question.) how can I fix it and why is it there? Thank you!

Comment: @Melloware: I think that OP means the background of the filmstrip below the big image is white in the showcase and it is part of the image in his case. The term 'fading' is misleading here. But if I'm wrong, I have no clue what the actual problem is. But if I'm right, I cannot see from the showcase how to get to the version of OP (css wise)

Comment: I can only sort of reproduc by giving the images an explicit height > 313px in the showcase. So it might be caused by some generic CSS. OP Should try to create a [mcve] (as should **always** be done)

Comment: And looking at the 'small filmstrip image' and the real big one, there is a problem with what is shown... Smaller image has more... Would have expected you (@AlexMi) to have seen that too.All plain css/html debugging

Comment: Any progress? Reaction?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you once again for your help! As mentioned, the problem here was due to the fact that my pictures have different proportions as those on the primeFaces showcase. After applying the work-around of the problem by adding style="width:95%" to the <p:graphicImage in the miminal working example, I do not have the problem anymore. Thank you once again!

Comment: Then my answer was 95% right and with the edit it is fully. You can accept it then

Comment: @Kukeltje Ive already done it. Would you please also have a look at my other problem? I added a minimal working example there:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985161/simulate-width-calc100-with-jquery-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this can be reproduced in the PrimeFaces showcase is by assigning an explicit height to the images. E.g. adding a css rule via a browser developer tool like `img {height: 364px}` makes this happen. This makes the big image btw not fully show what is in the thumbnail, it is cut-off at the right. And this can be seen in your screen dump as well. In the thumbnail there is way more visible of the sink on the right than in the big image. So this is with 100% certainty caused by some css that resizes the image or with a wrong aspect of the image compared to ttge dimensions  put om the `p:galeria`

The actual technical cause of this is however not visible in the code in your question. Next time, **always** create a [mcve], by reducing more and more and more until you are either left with a very small piece of (complete, verifyable, executable) code that demonstrates the problem, ***OR*** **you found the solution**...

Effectively this problem is all plain css html related and nothing PrimeFaces specific.

Comment: Thank you for your priceless effort, @Kukeltje! I will try to to reduce the problem and reproduce it (if possible) in an even smaller piece of code.

Comment: Start by inspecting the actual height of the image with a browser developer tool and if that is > 313px (the default of the galleria), it should be easily seen where the other height is coming from. But the step of creating an [mcve]  is a good one to learn how (and why) to always do it)

Comment: @Kukejltje: I added a minimal, working example and edited my question. You can download it from here: https://github.com/alexmivonwien/pf.gall.git

Comment: I kind a found a work-around of the problem by adding style="width:95%" to the <p:graphicImage in the miminal working example, but shall one always do it?! Thank you once again for your committment and always helping me in the best way!

Comment: Maybe your images have different proportions then the ones in the showcase. Then adapt the width and/or height of the galleria