# simulate width: calc(100%) - with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using HTML, CSS, mediaQuery, Javascript, jQuery and PrimeFaces, and I want to use the css property

```
calc(100% - 100px)
```

I've implement a javascript work around for old browsers, which do not support this property.

After reading several related questions, such as:

- [css width: calc(100% -100px); alternative using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery)
- [Run JavaScript function when the DOM is "ready"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992342/run-javascript-function-when-the-dom-is-ready)
- [Getting the width and height of a div after it finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459894/getting-the-width-and-height-of-a-div-after-it-finished-loading)

An excerpt from my code:

1.) my JavaScript function in my facelet:

```
        <ui:define name="search_results">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="primeicons/primeicons.css" library="primefaces"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="results.css" />
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="results.js"/>
        <script>
            // we need to execute the js function after the page load:
            // @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996316/how-to-execute-javascript-after-page-load
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    // twice in document.ready to execute after Primefaces callbacks
                      document.getElementById("homeDetailsPanelId").setAttribute("style","width:583px !important;");
                      var width = document.getElementById("homeDetailsPanelId").style.width;

                      alert (width);
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```

2.) My HTML and CSS code for the element in question:

```
 <div id="homeDetailsPanelId" class="col-7">
 <!-- more code here -->
 </div>
```

3.) My css file:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .col-7 {
        width:calc(100% - 395px);
    }

     /* more styles here */
   }
```

Minimal working example:

https://github.com/alexmivonwien/pf.css

When I load my page in any browser, I see that the javascript gets executed and the width of the element is set properly. However, after the javascript `alert()` shows up and I confirm it, the browser applies the css from the media query and the width of the element set with javascript is overwritten.

How can I make my JavaScript take precedence over the media query in the CSS?

Current result:

[image]

Comment: Normal CSS rules should not overwrite inline styles set via JS in the first place. Instead of setAttribute, can you try `[element].style.width = "583px !important"`? If that doesn’t work either, then you should show us a [mre]. // You are aware that doing this only once one page load, would not really be the equivalent of using `calc`, right? And support is pretty broad, so unless you really have to support browsers like IE < 9 (and can’t live with a “static” fallback value either), I would not bother too much with such workarounds in the first place …

Comment: @04FS I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I also added a minimal working example and adjusted my question accordingly. You can download it from here:   https://github.com/alexmivonwien/pf.css

Comment: @Kukeltje I added a minimal working example here: https://github.com/alexmivonwien/pf.css  Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an `important` value:

```
$('#homeDetailsPanelId').css('width', ''); //Remove width
var styles = $('exampleDiv').attr('style');
styles += 'width: ' + width + ' !important;'
$('#homeDetailsPanelId').attr('style', styles);
```

Comment: I have just tried :       document.getElementById("homeDetailsPanelId").setAttribute("style","width:583px !important;");  - nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

it might be a problem with presidency of id and class.try to give class in jquery and id in CSS like

css

```css
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    #homeDetailsPanelId {
        width:calc(100% - 395px);
    }

     /* more styles here */
   }
```

Jquery :

```js
   document.getElementByClassName("col-7").setAttribute("style","width:583px !important;");
```